# Should this be rephrased into saying no common factors but 1?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, factoring

This is from Discrete Mathematics and its Applications

> **Example** Prove that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational by giving a proof by contradiction.
>
> **Solution** Let $p$ be the proposition "$\sqrt{2}$ is irrational." To start a proof by contradiction, we suppose that $\neg p$ is true. Note that $\neg p$ is the statement "It is not the case that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational," which says that $\sqrt{2}$ is rational. We will show that assuming that $\neg p$ is true leads to a contradiction.
> If $\sqrt{2}$ is rational, there exist integers $a$ and $b$ with $\sqrt{2}=a/b$, where $b\ne 0$ and $a$ and $b$ have no common factors (so that the fraction $a/b$ is in lowest terms.) (Here, we are using the fact that every rational number can be written in lowest terms.) Because $\sqrt{2}=a/b$, when both sides of this equation are squared, it follows that

For the phrase "$a$ and $b$ have no common factors" , does that actually mean $a$ and $b$ have no common factors other than $1$? I feel like this would throw some readers off.

From what I read on http://www.infoplease.com/ipa/A0933353.html, $1$ can be a common factor of two numbers.

Comment: Mathematicians often ignore the case of $1$ being a factor because it is convenient to do so. Otherwise we would have to say "other than $1$" everywhere. So "other than $1$" is basically implied here, no need to say it. Often this is discussed in the early stages of an analysis course or algebra course.

Comment: The phrase "no common factors" usually does mean "apart from $1$", yes. To be more precise, it means "no common factor other than units", where unit is any factor of $1$, like $-1$ or $i=\sqrt{-1}$. This is done for the same reason that $1$ is not a prime: it saves three or four words every other sentence.

Comment: Alright that makes sense. Thanks guys !!